# Regex to match a number separated with multiple comma

Tags: java, regex

I'm working on identifying patterns using regex.

My use-case is to find strings of the following format

```
100,253,2586,3654
```

Here is what I've tried

```
(\d+\,+\d+\,*)+
```

but it doesn't seem to work properly.

Help me figure out the issue.

***Further to comments:***
pattern Should identify

```
1. Any combination of numbers separated by a comma  (eg: 123,465,798)  
2. shouldn't begin or end with comma (eg: ,123,46 )  
3. Decimals (eg: 123,465.2324)
```

Comment: You can extract digits from string, `\d+`

Comment: If you want to get a really good answer, you'll have to be more specific about what you want to match.  Is any mixture of digits and commas acceptable?  Can we start with a comma?  Can we end with a comma?  Are we allowed two consecutive commas?  Are we allowed any number of digits between the commas?  Can it start with a zero?  And so on.  If you're not specific about your requirements, then the simple `[\d,]+` is just as correct as any of the more complex answers.

Comment: Are you applying the regex to standalone strings, or searching for matches within a larger string?

Comment: searching for matches within a larger text block (like a paragraph)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "100,253,2586,3654";
    System.out.println(s.matches("((?<!^,)\\d+(,(?!$)|$))+"));
}
```

Edit : Regex explanation.

`((?<!^,)\\d+(,(?!$)|$))+")` ==>

> `\\d+` ==> matches one or more digits.
>
> `(?<!^,)` ==> Negative look-behind. Checks if String doesn't start with a ",".
>
> `(,(?!$)|$))+")` ==> checks
>   digits are - either followed by a comma and NOT followed by end of
>   String OR followed by end of String.

This will

> 1. Prevent a comma at the beginning.
> 2. prevent comma at the end.
> 3. multiple commas

Comment: Thank You. it works. Can you please add some documentation to that regex, it'll help others too. 
and how can I make it work for decimals like 100,253,2586,3654.999

Comment: @AlekhyaVemavarapu - I've updated my answer explaining the regexes used. I will look into checking decimals

Comment: @AlekhyaVemavarapu - This should work for your decimal thing - `s.matches("((?<!^,)\\d+(,|(\\.(?=\\d+$))(?!$)|$))+")`

Comment: No luck vinod. Thanks for the effort

Comment: @AlekhyaVemavarapu - Can you show me the input?. My regex works for `"100,253,2586.3654"`

Comment: 10,000,000,253,023,253,365,2536,2563,253 and 10,000,456,258.99

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96758/discussion-between-alekhya-vemavarapu-and-vinod-madyalkar).

Answer (score 1):

This should match the numerics you wish to grab. Note that it allows a trailing decimal point since you didn't specify anything about that consideration:

```
\d+(,\d+)*(\.\d*)?
```

Perhaps you need some lookaround to guarantee that matches are neither preceded nor followed by whatever characters you would have invalidate the match. But can't you have a period or comma as regular punctuation immediately after a number in a typical body of text?

Answer (score 0):

```
^\d+(?:,\d+)*$
```

This should do it for you.Your regex will not match only `123` .If that is not a possible case use

```
^\d+(?:,\d+)+$
```

Answer (score 0):

use this regex:

```
[^\,](\d+\.?,?)+[^\,]$
```

This should apply to your given cases

Comment: It would also match `123,`, which may or may not be a valid test case.

Comment: he didn't specify that when i was writing my answer, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble getting @TheLostMind's answer to work when I was trying to match the number within a string of other letters. I ended up going with:

```
 \d+(,\d+)*(\.\d+)?
```

(will need to escape those backslashes to use in your pattern string, i.e. `\\d+(,\\d+)*(\\.\\d+)?`)

**Note**: This doesn't quite answer the OP, as it doesn't check for no leading or trailing comma directly, but if the number does have that, it won't pull it from the CharSequence.

Explanation:

`\d+` matches one or many numbers

`(,\d+)*` matches zero or more groups of "a comma followed by one or many numbers"

`(\.\d+)?` matches zero or one groups of a decimal point followed by one or many numbers

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+(,\\d+)*(\\.\\d+)?");
Matcher m1 = pattern.matcher("100,253,2586,3654");
Matcher m2 = pattern.matcher("100,253,2586,3654.999");
Matcher m3 = pattern.matcher("10,000,000,253,023,253,365,2536,2563,253");
Matcher m4 = pattern.matcher("10,000,456,258.99");
Matcher m5 = pattern.matcher("10.99");
Matcher m6 = pattern.matcher("1");
Matcher m7 = pattern.matcher("Text on the left 100,253,2586,3654.00000 text on the right");
Matcher m8 = pattern.matcher("Text on the left ,100,253,2586,3654.00000, text on the right");

System.out.println("Matcher 1 matches " + m1.find() + " result: " + m1.group());
System.out.println("Matcher 2 matches " + m2.find() + " result: " + m2.group());
System.out.println("Matcher 3 matches " + m3.find() + " result: " + m3.group());
System.out.println("Matcher 4 matches " + m4.find() + " result: " + m4.group());
System.out.println("Matcher 5 matches " + m5.find() + " result: " + m5.group());
System.out.println("Matcher 6 matches " + m6.find() + " result: " + m6.group());
System.out.println("Matcher 7 matches " + m7.find() + " result: " + m7.group());
System.out.println("Matcher 8 matches " + m8.find() + " result: " + m8.group());
```

Prints:

```
Matcher 1 matches true result: 100,253,2586,3654
Matcher 2 matches true result: 100,253,2586,3654.999
Matcher 3 matches true result: 10,000,000,253,023,253,365,2536,2563,253
Matcher 4 matches true result: 10,000,456,258.99
Matcher 5 matches true result: 10.99
Matcher 6 matches true result: 1
Matcher 7 matches true result: 100,253,2586,3654.00000
Matcher 8 matches true result: 100,253,2586,3654.00000
```